# localtime() function is invoking ___lll_lock_wait_private() which is making the thread to go deadlock

Tags: c++, c, deadlock

I have seen many questions in which `___lll_lock_wait_private ()` is going into deadlock. But their call stack is different. Their code was calling `malloc()` or `free()` or `fork()`.

But in my case, I have a Log class, which is trying to print a log. That log is making my thread to go deadlock.

See below call stack,

```
#0  0x000000fff4c47b9c in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000fff4bf0364 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000fff4bee2c0 in localtime () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000fff5167188 in getTimeStr() () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/liblibLite.so
#4  0x000000fff516756c in LogClass::logBegin() () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/liblibLite.so
#5  0x000000fff5318c90 in DaemonCtrlServer::strtDaemon(daemonInfo&) () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/libDaemonCtlServer.so
#6  0x000000fff531abc0 in DaemonCtrlServer::restrtDiedDaemon(daemonInfo&) () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/libDaemonCtlServer.so
#7  0x000000fff531ae64 in DaemonCtrlServer::handleChildDeath() () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/libDaemonCtlServer.so
#8  0x00000000100080ac in sj_initd::DaemonDeathHandler() ()
#9  0x000000001000b8f8 in sj_initd::SignalHandler(int) ()
#10 0x00000000100080e8 in sj_initd_SigHandler::sj_initdSigHandler(int) ()
#11 <signal handler called>
#12 0x000000fff4bedc00 in __offtime () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#13 0x000000fff4bf02a8 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#14 0x000000fff4bee2c0 in localtime () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#15 0x000000fff5167188 in getTimeStr() () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/liblibLite.so
#16 0x000000fff516756c in LogClass::logBegin() () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/liblibLite.so
#17 0x000000fff52e868c in ConnectionOS::ProcessReadEvent() () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/libconnV2.so
#18 0x000000fff52ef354 in ConnectionOSManager::ProcessConns(fd_set*, fd_set*) () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/libconnV2.so
#19 0x000000fff52f0a0c in SocketsManager::ProcessFds(bool) () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/libconnV2.so
#20 0x000000fff52c51b4 in EventReactorBase::IO (this=0x19a65e80) at EventReactorBase.cpp:361
#21 0x000000fff52c457c in EventReactorBase::React (this=0x19a65e80) at EventReactorBase.cpp:419
#22 0x000000fff52c10cc in Task::Run (this=0x19a65e30) at Task.cpp:222
#23 0x000000fff52c1218 in startTask (t=0x19a65e30) at Task.cpp:152
#24 0x000000001000a9c4 in TaskManager::Start() ()
#25 0x0000000010007538 in main ()
```

sj_init is a daemon which monitors the live status of other daemons in a system. When a daemon dies(which closes the connection with sj_init), it tries to restart that daemon. Then, `startDaemon()` is trying to print a log, which is calling `getTimeStr()` which internally calling `___lll_lock_wait_private`

**Edit**

as `localtime` is not threadsafe, I tried with `localtime_r` but it also lead the thread to go into a deadlock. but acc. to `localtime_r` description this is threadsafe  function. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A signal handler may only call a very specific set of functions. Scroll down here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03 `localtime()` is not within this set.

Comment: If you read e.g. [this signal-safety (Linux) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) it does not list `localtime` as a signal-safe function.

Answer (score 2):

The programs blocks inside a signal handler in `__tz_convert()` being called from `localtime()`. The signal handler interrupted `__tz_convert()` being called from `localtime()`.

```
#0  0x000000fff4c47b9c in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000fff4bf0364 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000fff4bee2c0 in localtime () from /lib64/libc.so.6
...
#11 <signal handler called>
...
#13 0x000000fff4bf02a8 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#14 0x000000fff4bee2c0 in localtime () from /lib64/libc.so.6
...
#25 0x0000000010007538 in main ()
```

`localtime()` seems to **not** be reintrant.

A signal handler may only call a very specific set of functions. Scroll down here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03

`localtime()` is not within this set.

Signal handler should be short and simple.

You could set up a thread doing the formatting and logging which  for example via a pipe is being fed by the signal handler with all necessary information to format and log. The functions to do so *are* listed within the set linked above.

Comment: localtime is not   thread safe. so I tried with localtime_r() function. But still same issue persists. frommmm localtime_r documentation, it is stated that it is thread safe. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't do this kind of thing from a signal handler. Have the signal handler dispatch a thread to do this kind of work. You have `localtime` in your call stack twice. You are calling `localtime` while calling `localtime`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#4  0x000000fff516756c in LogClass::logBegin() () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/liblibLite.so
#16 0x000000fff516756c in LogClass::logBegin() () from /usr/sbin/sajet/sharedobj/liblibLite.so
```

Notice that `LogClass::logBegin` appears in your call stack twice?

You have two core problems.

1. You are calling `localtime` from a signal handler. That is not allowed.
2. You are looking at the wrong thread's stack. This thread got stuck in a deadlock caused by other threads and then was interrupted, getting stuck in the deadlock again. It's a victim of the deadlock (twice!). The perpetrator is another thread.

If you're going to log from a signal handlers, you need very tight control over all the code that runs in the signal handler and you need to pass the "heavy lifting" off to another thread that can safely call non-reentrant functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the process that is going to deadlock is a single thread process by design. It can not have another thread. The single thread is going to deadlock. currently I am trying to implement what localtime does, in a user-defined function to avoid using localtime. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: But there is a problem with above approach too, I need to know the timezone in a number format. Like for GMT+5:30 timezone, I need to have 5.5 as timezone. I don't know how to get this from system without hardcoding.

Comment: @ram914 Then have the log logic just add raw information to a collection that some other code converts to the necessary format. Store the raw time and call `localtime` after the signal handler returns.